# synergy-plug is there some kind of log or error control?

Tags: synergy

I configured synergy-plus server and client as described in the following url:
http://www.engadget.com/2005/08/09/how-to-share-your-keyboard-and-mouse-in-realtime-with-synergy/

I didn't find any info indicating that there is a log file or any error control to see if the client connect correctly. how can i troubleshoot ?

Trying to connect between Linux OS and Snow Leopard.
this is my server configuration file:
(music snow is the snow leopard, tux-in is the linux)

```
section: screens
tux-in.local:
music-snow:
end

section: links
tux-in.local:
    right = music-snow
music-snow:
    left = tux-in.local
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To troubleshoot, run:

`synergys -f -d DEBUG1`

This prevents synergy server from deamonizing and prints debug messages to the terminal.

To troubleshoot the client run:

`synergyc -f -d DEBUG1 ip.or.hostname.of.server`